# How and why does ~ vs its substituted form in path affect behavior of which / type?

Tags: ubuntu

If my PATH contains say `~/.local/bin`, the file in that location won't be discovered by `which`, but it will be discovered by `type`, and the file will be hashed. If I update PATH to `/home/me/.local/bin`, (which I expected to be the same only to find out some remarks is not), the `which` works now, so does `type` but given command is now NOT hashed.

Can someone explain that?

Comment: Related: Using `which` is discouraged. It does not see the world the way your shell does, which is what’s decisive. Check [this Q/A on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then).